# The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the currentUser uid using FirebaseUser but I may be doing it wrong.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```dart
FirebaseUser instructor = (await FirebaseUser.instance.currentUser()).uid;
```

And these are the errors that I get:

```
The await expression can only be used in an async function.
The getter 'instance' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseUser'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The module is called `FirebaseAuth`, not `FirebaseUser`. So the code would be:

```
FirebaseUser instructor = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

Note I also removed the `.uid` at the end, since you're assigning to a `FirebaseUser` reference. If you instead want to get the user's UID string, do:

```
var instructor = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid;
```